# How can i sort more than one table with Material Angular Sort?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my array-object `sortedData`:

[image]

A `*ngFor` is applied in the `Contas` as you can see in the template, each `Contas` position will be a table:

```
<div *ngFor="let tabelaAnuncioContas of sortedData?.Contas; let a = index">
    <table id="tabelaAnunciosB2W" matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event, a)">
         <tr>
            <th mat-sort-header="status">Status</th>
            <th>Miniatura</th>
            <th mat-sort-header="name">Título</th>
            <th mat-sort-header="qty">Quantidade</th>
            <th mat-sort-header="price">Valor</th>
            <th>Ações</th>
         </tr>
          ...
```

**in my TS:**

```
sortedData: any;

  sortData(sort: Sort) {
    const data = this.sortedData.slice();
    if (!sort.active || sort.direction === '') {
      this.sortedData = data;
      return;
    }

    this.sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = sort.direction === 'asc';
      switch (sort.active) {
        case 'status': return this.compare(a.status, b.status, isAsc);
        case 'name': return this.compare(a.name.toUpperCase(), b.name.toUpperCase(), isAsc);
        case 'qty': return this.compare(a.qty, b.qty, isAsc);
        case 'price': return this.compare(a.price, b.price, isAsc);
        case 'categories': return this.compare(a.categories.name.toUpperCase(), b.categories.name.toUpperCase(), isAsc)
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
  }

  compare(a: number | string, b: number | string, isAsc: boolean) {
    return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
  }
```

In my console i'm getting this error message:

> ERROR TypeError: this.sortedData.slice is not a function

This `sortedData` i'm setting in a http requisition:

```
this.sortedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.body))
```

**Edit:**

Changed to:

```
sortData(sort: Sort, indexTabela: number) {
    const data = this.anunciosB2w.Contas[indexTabela].Anuncio.products.slice();
    if (!sort.active || sort.direction === '') {
      this.sortedData = data;
      return;
    }

    this.sortedData.Contas[indexTabela].Anuncio.products = data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = sort.direction === 'asc';
      switch (sort.active) {
        case 'status': return this.compare(a.status, b.status, isAsc);
        case 'name': return this.compare(a.name.toUpperCase(), b.name.toUpperCase(), isAsc);
        case 'qty': return this.compare(a.qty, b.qty, isAsc);
        case 'price': return this.compare(a.price, b.price, isAsc);
        case 'categories': return this.compare(a.categories.name.toUpperCase(), b.categories.name.toUpperCase(), isAsc)
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
  }
```

Now the sort works, but when i sort 3 times, my sortedData is setted to null wtf

Comment: Can you check the type of sortedData? I would guess it is an object ( based on your screenshot ). Objects do not have a method called slice. Arrays do however.

Comment: @RMo please check my edit